# Can I use composer without installing it?

Tags: php, composer-php

I've noticed on a lot of open source user systems, like **UserFrosting** or **Drupal** they some how use composer, without the user actually having to install composer on to there server. I was just wondering how would I be able to do this, I've had a look around and can't find anyway of just using the files.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you could simply download the composer.phar file, and run it from CLI like:

```
cd ~/
wget https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
php composer.phar [command]
```

You'll need at least PHP v5.6.x and the mcrypt extension installed for the CLI SAPI.